# Login page responsible for different applications

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a workspace in which I have many applications based on the same schema.
Every applications has his own login page at the moment.

I want to build another application responsible for the login of all the other applications. 
The login will redirect the user to a main page that will show the links to the different modules (applications) based on the user type.

Note that only the `ADMIN` user can see the links to all the applications.
Different types of user will see only the links to the apps that they are authorized to access.

I read other related posts, I know I have to change the cookie name for all the app I want to share the authentication.

**But my question is:**

If I login successfully with a user different from the ADMIN, I am still able to access all the applications via URL, even if their link is not visible in my main page.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the use of authorisation schemes (see under Shared Components).

If you had an authorisation scheme per application you check on each page so that if the current user was authorised that application. Don't forget that each authorisation scheme would also allow users who have ADMIN access.

Hope this helps.

Just had another thought. Check out this post http://www.explorer-development.uk.com/securing-vulnerability-exploits-apex-part-2/ by Craig Sykes.

Activating Session State Protection and using Checksums would prevent a number of issues for you.